# Any Change in textbox will automatically check the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox, textbox

Hi I have coded a Grid view where we have one checkbox and two textbox. My need is that as we make any change in textbox like modify text from 0 to 1, the Checkbox should get automatically checked. This code is in asp.net and this can be done by javascript or Jquery.

Need code to do this activity.

Comment: This is node a code supplier website....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. 
Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example

**Html**

```
<input type="text"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

**Script**

```
$('input[type="text"]').keypress(function(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked","checked");
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fep7kb0o/)

Comment: Hi Manoj, Thanks It work but fails if we removed the check from checkbox and again type something in textbox. or we can say on first run it works but fails if check is removed.

Answer (score 1):

This will be Better answer of this question.. I initially debug by help of Manoj. Thanks again.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="selector"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"/>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('#selector').change(function () {
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', true); // Checks it
alert($('#selector').val());
});
```